# I want to get multiline logs in Splunk for my python service. How can I achieve that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, splunk, splunk-dashboard

I have a python service which is integrated with the splunk for checking logs. I am getting getting error message in splunk in split lines like in image [image: split line error]. I want to get the error in the same line. How can I achieve that using logging?

Answer (score 2):

By default, every line of input to Splunk is considered a separate event.  To change that, edit the props.conf file for the source type and change the `LINE_BREAKER` setting.  Set the value to a regular expression that contains a capture group where one event ends and the next begins.  I'd suggest such a regex, but can't do so without seeing more example data.

There are other props.conf settings you can use if `LINE_BREAKER` doesn't solve the problem.  For instance, `BREAK_ONLY_BEFORE`, `BREAK_ONLY_BEFORE_DATE`, or `MUST_BREAK_AFTER`.